# Java Swing JEditorPane not outputting empty paragraphs

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

After plugging HTML into a JEditorPane, I'm unable to read the HTML back out if there's empty paragraph elements. This is important for my project because I'm using it as an html editor where user's can create new paragraphs, but if they don't enter any content into the paragraphs they get erased on the next editor.getText(), which is confusing for the user.

After the editor pane loads if I call .getText() on it without making any changes, it has the following HTML structure:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="margin-top: 0">
  
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But then if i simply call

```
editor.setText(editor.getText())
System.out.println(editor.getText())
```

The output changes to

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to be able to get the HTML, modify it with JSoup, and re-insert it. Ideally i would have no loss at all when calling getText(). I've tried reading the HTML out instead using HTMLDocument:

```
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();    
        try {
            htmlKit_.write(writer,  htmlDoc_, 0, htmlDoc_.getLength());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String s = writer.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
```

But it gives me the same results. Is there any way I can preserve these empty tags? I need to preserve empty list tags as well, empty table tags, etc. Here's my code. Thanks for your help

TESTEDITOR:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TestEditor implements ActionListener {

    JButton printHTMLButton_;
    JEditorPane editor_;
    HTMLEditorKit htmlKit_;
    HTMLDocument htmlDoc_;
    
    public TestEditor() {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,600);     
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.red);
    
        printHTMLButton_ = new JButton("HTML");
        printHTMLButton_.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(printHTMLButton_);
        
        editor_ = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");
        editor_.setEditable(true);
        editor_.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        panel.add(editor_);
        
        htmlKit_ = new HTMLEditorKit();
        editor_.setEditorKit(htmlKit_);
        
        htmlDoc_ = (HTMLDocument)editor_.getDocument();
        
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == printHTMLButton_) {
            System.out.println(editor_.getText());
            editor_.setText(editor_.getText());
            System.out.println(editor_.getText());


            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();    
            try {
                htmlKit_.write(writer,  htmlDoc_, 0, htmlDoc_.getLength());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String s = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestEditor();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe change to `<p style="margin-top: 0">&nbsp;</p>`

Comment: Yeah that's kind of quick and dirty fix but as the program develops having &nbsp; all over the place will cause problems. Isn't there a way to tell the editor "look why dont you just return all the html? I'm pretty sure the empty <p> tags are in the editor model, I just can't get to them??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
htmlKit_.write(writer,  htmlDoc_, 0, htmlDoc_.getLength());
```

Last night, for your previous question, I was playing with the above statement to try to get only the HTML for your paragraph (so the bold tag would also be included). However, no matter what parameters I passed for the start/length I always got the entire document.

Today, I played with the length:

```
//htmlKit_.write(writer,  htmlDoc_, 0, htmlDoc_.getLength());
System.out.println(htmlDoc_.getLength());
htmlKit_.write(writer,  htmlDoc_, 0, 2);
```

and magically the paragraph tag is now included in the output.

The write(...) method of the editor kit obviously has some problem.

Comment: Ok, so I've been playing with it some more and it seems like if I set the length to some arbitrarily high number, such as 1000000, I can get the full html content including empty tags (I hope) no matter the content (I hope). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GeoffL played more with the write() metod of the HTMLWriter and I think I understand the parameters a litter better. I may have a suggestion for your previously deleted question on how to extract the text, including the "bold" tags for the text on the line where the caret is placed. If you undelete the question I can post my suggestion.

Comment: Ah Ok thanks camickr I'm not really sure how to undelete a post though, I can't seem to find the post in my list of posts anymore. still trying.

Comment: @GeoffL, look at your user profile and select the "questions" tab. At the bottom left of the page you should see a "recently deleted questions" link.

Comment: Ok I did it. I think I'm going to move on from java swing to try JavaFX though because there's just so many dinky little problems with the Swing editor which is a huge part of my program. JavaFX has a much better HTML editor from what I can tell, and seems easier to use (so far)

Comment: The HTML support in Swing has never been that good and I've never had much luck manipulating it. Although I do have a little better understanding after your last couple of questions. Your other question has been updated with my latest suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I'm a Java newb but am trying to learn very fast hence all these rapid-fire questions. I got into Swing because its the first thing that popped up when I searched Java GUI, but I realize now maybe that was a mistake given how old it is. I'm also doing my best to conform better to stackoverflow requirements. You've been the most helpful person here and I do appreciate it thank you.